# How to select the duplicate and unique values from multiple list

Tags: python, list

How to create an other list which contains most repeated items from all the list on the top and unique items below. I tried it with for loop but I can only compare list1 with rest where I'm missing the items in rest of them. How to solve this. Thank You.

```py
List1 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange']
List2 = ['Car', 'Bike', 'Mango', 'Truck', 'Orange']
List3 = ['Watermelon', 'Banana', 'Bus', 'Grapes', 'Truck']


repeated_list = []
non_repeated_list = []

        
for item in List1:
    if item in List2:
        if item in List3:
            repeated_list.append(item)
        else:
            non_repeated_list.append(item)
```

Solution:

```
repeated_list = ["Banana", "Mango", "Orange", "Grapes", "Truck"]
non_repated_list = ["Apple", "Car", "Bike", "Watermelon", "Bus"]
```

> Then merging the two list but the problem is I cannot include unique
> items of other list as I loop and compare with list1 only. So how to
> include other unique items from other list as well.

Comment: Please share the code you used to generate the given input and what you tried yourself to solve the problem.

Comment: What is your criteria for including elements in the solution? Shows up more than once? Shows up `>= n` times? I only see `Car` once, in `List2`, but it's in the solution, why?

Comment: It would help if you provided the lists as Python lists instead of plain text.

Comment: @blorgon, Most repeated values need to be on top of the list and unique values will be on bottom. Based on number of times it repeated in all the 3 list.

Comment: Well none of the items you've provided are present in all three lists.

Comment: "Truck" should be in `repeated_list`. OP, please edit to fix this error, and make the data copy-pasteable for others (i.e., assuming these are strings we're talking about, edit the post so that the data is given as strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count all three lists, then use its [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method to get your desired output:

```
List1 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange']
List2 = ['Car', 'Bike', 'Mango', 'Truck', 'Orange']
List3 = ['Watermelon', 'Banana', 'Bus', 'Grapes', 'Truck']

# ---

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain(List1, List2, List3))
for k, tally in c.most_common():
    print(k, tally)
```

Here I'm also printing the tally per item just to be verbose.

Output:

```
Banana 2
Mango 2
Grapes 2
Orange 2
Truck 2
Apple 1
Car 1
Bike 1
Watermelon 1
Bus 1
```

If you don't like [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), you could use a simple for-loop:

```
c = Counter()
for L in List1, List2, List3:
    c.update(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can flatten all the lists, cast to `set` to get the unique items and then get counts in the flattened list for each unique item.

```py
flattened = List1 + List2 + List3 # can use sum(list_of_lists, []) if you have more lists
uniques = set(flattened)
descending_by_freq = sorted(uniques, key=flattened.count, reverse=True)
```

Output:

```py
>>> descending_by_freq
['Truck', 'Mango', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grapes', 'Bike', 'Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Bus', 'Car']
```

And just to show the counts:

```py
>>> {s: flattened.count(s) for s in uniques}
{'Bike': 1, 'Truck': 2, 'Mango': 2, 'Watermelon': 1, 'Banana': 2, 'Orange': 2, 'Grapes': 2, 'Apple': 1, 'Bus': 1, 'Car': 1}
```

EDIT: OP moved the goal posts a little after I'd posted my answer. Since OP now seems to want two separate lists, one for repeated elements and one for non-repeated:

```py
repeated = [s for s in uniques if flattened.count(s) > 1]
non_repeated = [s for s in uniques if flattened.count(s) == 1]
```

There are much more efficient solutions, but I believe my answer is still useful to those new to Python.

Comment: You're right, I had that in there from an old iteration of the solution. Forgot to remove it. Thanks.

Comment: Every time I edit, it feels like OP moves the goal posts.

Comment: Counter is much more efficient for this, no?

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't hurt to show more traditional approaches to help OP learn basic Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to merge all lists into 1 and then count the frequency from each  instance and store them in a dictionary, from there you can get the most/least used ones

```
list1 = ["b" , "c"]
list2 = ["a", "b" , "e"]
list3 = ["e" , "c", "b"]

list_merged = list1 + list2 + list3

def count_frequency(my_list): 
    # Create an empty dictionary  
    freq = {} 
    for item in my_list: 
            if (item in freq): 
                    freq[item] += 1
            else: 
                    freq[item] = 1
    sorted_freq = {k: v for k, v in sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
    print(sorted_freq)

count_frequency(list_merged)
```